# How to Insert TIMESTAMP Column into Redshift

Tags: amazon-web-services, timestamp, amazon-redshift

I created a table in Redshift:

```
create table myTable (
       dateTime TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
       ...
);
```

However, when I try to insert a record that contains a `dateTime` of, I get an error from `stl_load_errors`.

> 20080215 04:05:06.789

Since I took this timestamp from the [docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_Date_and_time_literals.html), I would've expected it to have worked.

The error logs from Redshift show:

> Invalid timestamp format or value [YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS]

However, I'd like to include 3 extra seconds, example: `2015-02-01 15:49:35.123`.

How do I need to modify my timestamp field to insert it with the extra precision on seconds?

Comment: I could upload the following JSON key-value into Redshift via the `COPY` command: `"putDateTime":"2009-11-17 10:45:32.021394"`. However, Redshift stored it as `2009-11-17 10:45:32` in the `putDateTime` column. Note that I created the column as a `TIMESTAMP` type.

Answer (score 32):

TL;DR - When importing into Redshift from an S3 file force the imported data to have the default time format of `'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS'`that Redshift expects in order to get a precision past seconds, otherwise it will be truncated.

I ran into this same issue while trying to upload to pull in from S3. My original JSON has a timestamp like this. `{ "updated_at" : "2014-12-08T21:14:49.351638" }`. However when I went to pull it into Redshift I needed to set the format, which included the T before the time.

```
COPY schema.temp_table FROM 's3://s3-bucket/file-name'
    WITH CREDENTIALS 'aws_access_key_id=access-key;aws_secret_access_key=secret-key'
    format as json 'auto'
    timeformat 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MI:SS';
```

This imported everything, however the time was always truncated to seconds, so I would end up with `2014-12-08 21:14:49` in Redshift.

The [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_COPY_command_examples.html#r_COPY_command_examples-load-a-time-datestamp) looks like this should import with precision out to 6 places, but this was not the case.

I decided to try out the default format `'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS'` for importing to Redshift so I had to change my Postgres database to export the JSON for date fields in the correct format `to_char(updated_at, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.SSSSS') as updated_at`.

After making this change the new JSON exported as `{ "updated_at" : "2014-12-08 21:14:49.351638" }` and I set the timeformat for the import into Redshift as the default `format as json 'auto' timeformat 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS';`

By making this change to use the default timeformat Redshift now imported the timestamps with the correct precision!

Answer (score 18):

`timeformat 'auto'` and `dateformat 'auto'` worked well on my format, `2017-11-02T21:04:03.108Z`. Documentation at http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/automatic-recognition.html

Answer (score 6):

In your copy command please add this **timeformat 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS';**

Refer [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_COPY_command_examples.html#r_COPY_command_examples-load-a-time-datestamp) for more details