# How to convert TIMESTAMP into VARCHAR and save it into another table in Redshift?

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, timestamp, amazon-redshift, varchar

I have a table and have some values like below,

```sql
CREATE TABLE school_1__test.tstamp(
    timeofday TIMESTAMP,
    timeofdaytz TIMESTAMP
);

insert into school_1__test.tstamp values('Jun 1,2008  09:59:59', 'Jun 1,2008 09:59:59 EST' );
insert into school_1__test.tstamp values('Dec 31,2008 18:20','Dec 31,2008 18:20');
insert into school_1__test.tstamp values('Jun 1,2008  09:59:59 EST', 'Jun 1,2008 09:59:59');

select * from school_1__test.tstamp;

-----------------------------------------------
     timeofday        |      timeofdaytz
-----------------------------------------------
2008-06-01 09:59:59.0 | 2008-06-01 09:59:59.0
2008-12-31 18:20:00.0 | 2008-12-31 18:20:00.0
2008-06-01 09:59:59.0 | 2008-06-01 09:59:59.0
```

Now I have another table like below,

```sql
CREATE TABLE school_1__test.date_test(
    timeofday VARCHAR
);
```

I want to insert data from `tstamp` table to `date_test` table and tried with each and every command(commented) in below statement,

```sql
INSERT INTO school_1__test.date_test (
    select to_char(timeofday, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS')
    --select convert(timestamp, timeofday)
    --select cast(timeofday as timestamp)
    --select to_timestamp("timeofday",'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS')
    --select timeofday::timestamp
    --select to_date(timeofday,'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS')
    --select convert(varchar, timeofday::timestamp)
    --select convert(varchar, to_timestamp("timeofday",'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS'))
    from school_1__test.tstamp
);
```

But when I see the table data it displays only `DATE` details, cannot find `TIME` details.

```sql
select * from school_1__test.date_test;

----------
timeofday
----------
2008-06-01
2008-06-01
2008-12-31
```

Before before conversion I checked each and every `SELECT` statements, it displays the correct output.

```sql
select to_char(timeofday, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SSTZ')
--select convert(timestamp, timeofday)
--select cast(timeofday as timestamp)
--select to_timestamp("timeofday",'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS')
--select timeofday::timestamp
--select to_date(timeofday,'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS')
--select convert(varchar, timeofday::timestamp)
--select convert(varchar, to_timestamp("timeofday",'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS'))
from school_1__test.tstamp

-------------------
      to_char
-------------------
2008-06-01 09:59:59
2008-12-31 06:20:00
2008-06-01 09:59:59
```

I checked [How to Insert TIMESTAMP Column into Redshift](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28287434/13031412) issue, but I don't use any `COPY` command here and all the data inserted by myself, so nothing get anything from `S3`.

What is the solution to get both `DATE` and `TIME` parts when using that `INSERT` command?

Comment: thank you @Jasen, just change. but the problem is same as before.

Comment: hmm it's working when I try it in postgresql. to me it looks like a redshift bug.

Comment: Thank you so much @Jasen for your time and effort, I tried with `DBeaver`. It's working perfectly in Amazon Redshift console, but it's very slow. Anyway I won't use `DBeaver` anymore. In `DBeaver` every time we have to sync after data insertion, it's useless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It worked fine for me in Amazon Redshift, using the Query Editor in the Amazon Redshift console.

I used your exact commands (without the schema name).

Comment: Thank you so much @john-rotenstein for your time and effort, I tried with `DBeaver`. It's working perfectly in Amazon Redshift console, but it's very slow. Anyway I won't use `DBeaver` anymore. In `DBeaver` every time we have to sync after data insertion, it's useless.

Comment: I know that some SQL clients can modify results and cause confusing output! I like using DbVisualizer -- it seems to know every database that's out there.